# Mailchimp dynamic content

Tags: mailchimp

I'm creating a "jobs by email" mailshot for our company and am investigating moving to MailChimp from our current marketing provider.  We have a database containing locations, keywords and email addresses of people subscribed and run a script to match jobs recently added to our website to an email address.  This generates an HTML table which is bespoke to each email address.

What I now want to do is import this section of bespoke HTML into a generic campaign so it looks something along the lines of

```
Generic email stuff
Here are your latest jobs

Job Title                   Location             Salary            Apply
Bespoke title1              Bespoke Location1    Bespoke Salary1   Link1
Bespoke title2              Bespoke Location2    Bespoke Salary2   Link2
Bespoke title3              Bespoke Location3    Bespoke Salary3   Link3

More generic email stuff
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in straight MailChimp, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Basically, you would need to generate a large text file with each user's bespoke html results wrapped in `*|IF:EMAIL=user_x@email.com|* <!-- user_x content --> *|END:IF|*` [conditional merge tags](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-conditional-smart-merge-tags-work). This would get unwieldy in a hurry.

Better for this would be to use the [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) service, where you would build your template in MailChimp [with dynamic fields to hold your bespoke content](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694868-Getting-Started-with-Templates), then use the [Mandrill API](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21714881-How-do-I-access-Mandrill-for-sending-email-) to send individual emails to your subscribers either one by one or in batches.